# Tdom Tag TCL/Tk

Tags: tcl

I need help with generating a Xml document. 
I would like this result:

```
<Poly Unit="millimeter" Visible="on" XRGB="0x80000000" Select="off">
      <File>C:\file</File>
      <ModelMatrix>
      <MatrixXAxis X="1" Y="1" Z="0"/>
      </ModelMatrix>
 </Poly>
```

and now i have this result

```
 <Poly Unit="millimeter" Visible="on" XRGB="0x80000000" Select="off">
                    <File>C:\file</File>
                    <ModelMatrix>
                    <MatrixXAxis>X='1' Y='1' Z='0'</MatrixXAxis>
                    </ModelMatrix>
  </Poly>
```

I try `appendXML` ,but my tag is always at the end.
My code below :

```
set fp [open $file r]
set doc [dom parse [read $fp]]
close $fp

set node [$doc selectNodes "/Vc/Setup/Build"]
set node [$node selectNodes {//Component[@Name='Stock']}]

dom createNodeCmd elementNode Poly
dom createNodeCmd elementNode File
dom createNodeCmd elementNode ModelMatrix
dom createNodeCmd elementNode MatrixXAxis
dom createNodeCmd textNode t


$node appendFromScript {
Poly {Unit millimeter Visible on XRGB 0x80000000 Select off} {
File { t "C:/file"}
    ModelMatrix {} {
        MatrixXAxis { t "X='1' Y='1' Z='0'"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to congratulate you on a well-asked question. You say what you've got and what you want. It made it a pleasure to answer, unlike so many other questions on Stack Overflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are wanting to specify the `X`, `Y`, and `Z` as attributes, not as body content. As such, you should pass them in as a dictionary to `MatrixXAxis` via its optional argument, just as you do with `Poly`.

```tcl
$node appendFromScript {
    Poly {Unit millimeter Visible on XRGB 0x80000000 Select off} {
        File { t "C:/file"}
        ModelMatrix {} {
            MatrixXAxis {X 1 Y 1 Z 0} {}
        }
    }
}
```

(i.e., `MatrixXAxis {X 1 Y 1 Z 0} {}` instead of `MatrixXAxis { t "X='1' Y='1' Z='0'"}`)

If I do `$node asXML` after that, I get something like this:

```xml
<Poly Unit="millimeter" Visible="on" XRGB="0x80000000" Select="off">
    <File>C:/file</File>
    <ModelMatrix>
        <MatrixXAxis X="1" Y="1" Z="0"/>
    </ModelMatrix>
</Poly>
```

Looks right to me…

Comment: perfect i don't know dictionary with {} at end. Thank you.

Comment: @Mkn: The `createNodeCmd` makes commands that are all the same in how they work; with one argument, the argument is a script to generate the body of element, and with two arguments, the first argument is a dictionary to define the attributes and the second is a body script. You were using it for `Poly` just fine; just a matter of using it for `MatrixXAxis` too.